# ES6 default parameters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to use default parameter values, but getting this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
```

Is this working in node now? I'm using 5.9.1

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters

I also tried messing with passing flags to node without success.

```
  node --harmony_default_parameters
```

It seems like a basic part of ES6 so hope it would be working by now!

Comment: Please add your script

Comment: see below @RIYAJKHAN

Answer (score 2):

> Is this working in node now?

Not yet. It's only available for testing under a flag. V8 v4.9 (released in Chrome 49) is the earliest stable version of V8 that supports default parameters. Nodejs v5.9.1 runs on top of V8 `v4.6.85.31`. You can use the command `node -p process.versions.v8` for checking the current V8 version. Also, you have to wait until Nodejs v6.x for a complete support of default parameters. You can see [this issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/5926) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be a result of mixing ES6 style functions:

```
  getReply: (input, userId = null) => {   // No good

  getReply: function(input, userId = null) {  // OK
```

Comment: You mean you used an arrow function without supplying the respective option, and that was the actual reason for it not to work? The first snippet is certainly legal ES6 as well

Comment: yes, it seems that only old style JS function syntax works. I'm actually using Typescript compiler, but checked the output JS and it was there as is.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the list of what ES6 features are currently supported by Node [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/). As it stands, it doesn't look like default paremeters are implemented, or at least not fully.